# Updating JTextArea in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, repaint

In my program I load a `JTextArea` to display some text when I click a button.  I've added the `ActionListener` and written a `loadQuestion()` method, but for some reason the component is not updating.  The component is contained in another file which I access via `get()` and `set()` methods.  I ran the `repaint()` and `revalidate()` methods in the loadQuestion () method and again in the `setTextArea()` method, but it still doesn't seem to work!! Any pointers would be appreciated - thanks in advance

```
public void loadQuestion () {
    JTextArea tempArea = quizDisplay.getTextArea();
    String text = "Hello World!!";
    tempArea.append("Hi");
    quizDisplay.setTextArea(tempArea);
    quizDisplay.revalidate();
    quizDisplay.repaint();

}
```

Comment: I don't think your question is currently answerable given the information that has been presented so far, that we need more information to venture more than a guess. I'll guess anyway -- are you sure that the quizDisplay object that you're calling methods on is the one that is being displayed? If this doesn't help, seriously consider giving us more information, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Also note that once you append text or set text on a JTextArea, it will display and calls to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` are completely unnecessary.

Comment: May try adding quizDisplay.updateUI(). You are sure that this method is getting called right?

Comment: Also, since you're getting the JTextArea from the quizDisplay object, I doubt that you need to pass it back in via your `setTextArea(...)` method, since it's probably already "set" as the object's JTextArea. Again, this can only be a guess as we're missing important pieces to your puzzle.

Comment: @thinksteep: No -- there is absolutely no reason to call `updateUI()` in a Swing application unless you're changing the look and feel. This recommendation will only confuse the issue and possibly add bad code to the original poster's project, and you may wish to remove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally when you append some text to a visible `JTextArea`, there is no need to call `revalidate` or `repaint` yourself. The `JTextArea` knows it has been changed, and will take care of its repaint.
There is also no need to set the text area again.

Furthermore, all Swing related operations should happen on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).

So your code would end up looking like

```
public void loadQuestion () {
    JTextArea tempArea = quizDisplay.getTextArea();
    tempArea.append("Hi");
}
```

and the `loadQuestion` method should be called on the EDT which is normally the case when it is called from the `ActionListener` when the button is pressed.

Check out the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for an example of [using a JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextDemoProject/src/components/TextDemo.java), where they do more or less the same (a quote from the source code to which I linked)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String text = textField.getText();
    textArea.append(text + newline);
    textField.selectAll();

    //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
    //was a selection in the text area.
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
}
```

Comment: I agree that there's no need to call `revalidate` or `repaint` (see my comments to the original question as it states the same thing), but on the other hand, neither of these calls will ever cause the original poster's problem. Your answer gives good suggestions but does not come close to solving the original problem, one that I think can't be solved without more information.

Comment: I was in doubt whether to post it as answer or as comment, but it was a bit long for a comment. When/if the question gets updated and my answer is irrelevant, I have no problem deleting it again

Comment: I wouldn't delete it as again, it does give correct and helpful suggestions. 1+ vote for those. But we'll have to wait to see if the OP ever comes back and gives us more information before we can find out what the solution to the original problem should be.

Comment: I am really sorry guys - it seems I made a critical mistake with the actionListener!  Really sorry to have used your time for no reason.  I had copied and pasted the implementation of an actionlistener for one of my other buttons and I had forgotten to update one of the references... again i'm really sorry